# accessing checkbox created in codebehind using string builder

Tags: c#, asp.net

i created an html table in code behind using append method from string builder class and i give it data from data base and i added a check box for each row in the table 
but now i don't know how to access these check boxes to delete selected rows from the table

here is my c# code

```
    public void GetDataFirstTime() 
{
    string LogedInUser = Request.Cookies["CLGN"].Value.ToString();


    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

    String result = String.Empty;
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRConnection"].ConnectionString);
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select MessageNum , Message , SenderName ,Date from Message where ReciverUserName=@run", cnn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@run", LogedInUser);

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select Max(MessageNum) from Message where ReciverUserName=@run ",cnn);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@run", LogedInUser);



    HttpCookie Max = new HttpCookie("MMI");
    Max.Value = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    Response.Cookies.Add(Max);


    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    html.Append("<div id = xxx> ");

    html.Append("<table border='1'>");
    html.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        html.Append("<th>");
        html.Append(col.ColumnName);
        html.Append("</th>");
    }

    html.Append("</tr>");

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<td>");
            html.Append(row[col.ColumnName]);
            html.Append("</td>");
        } 

        html.Append("<td>");
        html.AppendLine("<td><input TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME= CheckDel'" + row.ToString() + "'</td>");
        html.Append("</td>");

        html.Append("</tr>");
    }
    html.Append("</table>");
    html.Append("</div>");
    cnn.Close();

    Response.Write(html);
}
```

so can anyone help me in this please

Comment: Don't use StringBuilder to output HTML from ASP.NET. This usage specifically creates very invalid HTML, check your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to correct the code that creates the checkboxes. Right now it produces this HTML code:

```
<td><td><input TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME= CheckDel'System.Data.DataRow'</td></td>
```

That will be interpreted by the browser as:

```
<td></td>
<td>
  <input type="CHECKBOX" name="CheckDel'System.Data.DataRow'</td">
</td>
```

As you have nested table cell tags in each other, the browser will end the first cell before starting the next. As there is no closing bracket for the input tag, it will end it using the closing bracket of the `</td>` tag, including `</td` in the name of the checkbox. The `row.ToString()` doesn't get anything from the data row, it returns the name of the class, i.e. `"System.Data.DataRow"`.

I assume that you want to use some data from the data row to create the checkbox name, that would be something like this:

```
html.Append("<td>");
html.Append("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"CheckDel").Append(row["id"]).Append("\">");
html.Append("</td>");
```

Now any checkbox that is checked will be included in the form data when you do a postback, looking similar to this (the default value for a checkbox is `"on"`):

```
CheckDel42=on
```

You can use the `Request.Form` collection to check for the checkboxes. Loop through the items in the data row and check for the corresponding form value, something like:

```
if (Request.Form["CheckDel" + row["id"]] != null) {
  // the checkbox was checked for this item
}
```

Comment: sorry for this question  but i'm little new in coding
how i can loop throw checkboxes

Comment: and delete selected row from database according to checked box

Comment: @AhmadA.Al-Dwairi: You can't loop through the checkboxes, because they are not returned separately. You can loop through all data in the `Request.Form` collection and get those which starts with `"CheckDel"` (providing of course that no other fields starts with that), or you can get the data table and loop through the items to check if the corresponding checkbox was checked (using the code above).

Comment: ok got it bro ... 
now how to delete that record (row) from database

Comment: @AhmadA.Al-Dwairi: If I understand your table layout correctly you would use a command with a query like `"delete from Message where MessageNum = @id"`, set the parameter from the id that the checkbox corresponds to, and use `ExecuteNonQuery` to run the query.